# Slice-of-life-ish random comedy manga with interconnected vignettes

Tags: nickelodeon

Each chapter is a vignette that's usually in no way related to the other chapters, except for re-occurring characters who show up in multiple chapters to tie them together as being in the same universe (or alternate universes, I guess).

I can only remember 2 chapters at the moment, one clearly, the other not so much.

One had two guys. They went out drinking (I think) and one (blonde with glasses, IIRC) fell asleep. The other, a shaggy-haired brunette (or something) kisses the blonde. Blonde wakse up. Shaggy says something like "I wish I'd done this sooner. I guess my time's run out." It's revealed Shaggy either died before that outing or was in a coma and then died that night.

Another chapter had a group of girls (they were all in gym shorts, I think, so they might've been a volleyball team or something) hiding in a shed or gym equipment shed. They're all deathly afraid of having to venture outside looking for help, as they send one from their group at a time to look for help and wait to see if they return because there's a monster or murderer waiting outside to murder them all.

They play a game where each person in turn has to name an item/person/whatever within a given subject whose name begins with the same letter as the last letter of the previous word.  They cannot repeat words. Head Bitch uses a word that forces the next girl to repeat a word as there's no other word that fits the bill. The girl is despondent, screaming about how Head Bitch knew that word could not be followed up with an allowed word, but is sent outside. Head Bitch then tells the others how she knew very well she was signing that girl's death warrant and how they all hated the girl that was just sent outside, anyway.

They start the next round of the game after a while. The girl before Head Bitch uses the word Head Bitch used to doom the previous runner. Chapter ends.

Answer (score 4):

This is [Nickelodeon](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=58407) by Douman Seiman. The latter word game you mention is probably the shiritori game in chapter 6, and the former story with the two guys is from chapter 7.

Comment: @user5024 If this answered your question, remember that you can mark it as the "accepted" answer by clicking on the checkmark to the right, beneath the voting buttons.